# VS2010- app runs super slow in debugger on new PC

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I maintain a C#/WPF app which controls some industrial processes, using Visual Studio 2010.   I just got a new Windows 7 PC to replace the old XP clunker I had been using.

On the old PC there was no noticeable difference in performance whether I run the app via *Start Without Debugging* or *Start Debugging*.   An operation that took 5 seconds in one case took 5 seconds in the other.

On the new PC running via *Start Debugging* is **25X** slower, i.e., a 5 second operation takes over 2 minutes!   The is making debugging very tedious.

How do I analyze why running in the Visual Studio debugger is so much slower on my new PC?      The new PC is in every respect a higher-performance PC - quad-core, faster memory bandwidth, bigger CPU caches, etc.   So I'm assuming that it's something about the settings of Visual Studio.   I can't compare them since I've already uninstalled VS2010 from the old PC.

Comment: There are not that many things that take over 50 billion cpu cycles.  This is an environmental problem.  Anti-malware always first, make an exclusion for your project directories.  Next are network timeouts, disable the symbol server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "~VisualStudio directory~\Common7\IDE" in exclusions in your antivirus. I it will improve performance, Also try to run a registry cleaner and clear temporary files.